# Fix uneven and sloped plywood subfloor

Tags: flooring, subfloor, vinyl-flooring

We recently moved into an old townhouse and are renovating the entire second floor. The 10-year-old laminate flooring is squeaky and uneven, so we removed all of them and put down SPC vinyl flooring. However, some areas still feel hollow when stepped on. On the worst areas, the planks go down when I press on it with a finger.

Our contractor did some fixing on the plywood subfloor before installing the planks but I would like to know if there were a better way to do it.

What the contractor did:

1. driving a lot of screws wherever the subfloor squeaks
2. putting cement (leftover from installing bathroom wall tiles) into lower areas

I was suscipious about the use of the cement instead of a proper self-leveling compound polymer. The contractor suggested that a self-leveling compound cannot be used because:

1. the area is too large (500 sqft)
2. the subfloor is sloped -- about 1½ inch height difference over a 4ft span

Now that the new flooring installing and new baseboard installed + painted, but there are still highs and lows on the floor. I start to deeply regret not doing more fixing prior to installing the new flooring.

Are the contractor's claims true? Does adding a layer of thick OSB prior fixing the problem better? The doors do have a large gap between the bottom and the floor.

Comment: Is the floor *flat* (not necessarily level) after what he did?

Comment: @Huesmann Not perfectly flat. There are still highs and lows. It's *wavy*.